# Azure B2C - Failed to acquire token silently

Tags: azure, adal, azure-ad-b2c

I'm building an application with ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI using this template : [Azure AD B2C WebApp / WepAPI](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet).  I've configured my Azure B2C AD through the web.config files and when i click "Sign in" i see my identity providers. Login works so far (i see my username on the top right corner) and i'm able to execute the "To-Do List"-Action.

But a soon as i stop the debugger and restart the Application by pressing F5, i get an error when i click on "To-Do List"-Action again.

**Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken text** --> [Code](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/blob/7c6221ba04c12da8c2c84187ec695b744cf3cc99/TaskWebApp/Controllers/TasksController.cs#L41)

This happens, cause the user is still authenticated, but the [NaiveSessionCache](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/blob/7c6221ba04c12da8c2c84187ec695b744cf3cc99/TaskWebApp/Utils/NaiveSessionCache.cs#L12-L12) is empty after the applications restart. A possible solution would be, to store the token in the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived Handler, but i looks a little bit weird to me

```cs
    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
    {
        string userObjectID = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant, string.Empty, string.Empty);
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        string mostRecentPolicy = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(Startup.AcrClaimType).Value;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(notification.Code, new Uri(redirectUri), credential, new string[] { clientId }, mostRecentPolicy);

        // Store token in ClaimsIdentity
        notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Token", result.Token));
    }
```

- How do i correct retrieve the bearer token using AuthenticationContext-class for further use in my Angular-SPA client?
- Is it a good idea to store the token as a claim within the [OnAuthorizationCodeReceived Handler](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/blob/7c6221ba04c12da8c2c84187ec695b744cf3cc99/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L112)?
- The solution uses the [Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/4.0.209160138-alpha)  package. Is [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.24.304111323)  still not supporting Azure B2C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cache is empty because it is not being persisted anywhere. Check out http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/09/the-new-token-cache-in-adal-v2/. Search for EFADALTokenCache and you will find the implementation that will help you persist the cache to some storage.

Azure B2C will only be supported via the new library called MSAL available at  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client. This library is still under preview.

Comment: can you accept the answer if it helped you. It will help others as well.

Comment: NaiveSessionCache persist token in session state, that suppose to be available during the whole user session.It is used in samples.Is it not sufficient? Why you prefer storing in DB rather then in Session? I have related question   [Is it OK to use NaiveSessionCache from Azure-Samples Azure Active Directory OpenId Connect](//stackoverflow.com/q/41864737)